# Error using py.linalg.lstsq; UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'lstsq_n' input 0 from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'

Tags: python, numpy

How do i solve the below please, "UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'lstsq_n' input 0 from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind' ",

sorry i am a beginner, my numpy is import as py

```
# The matrix consisting of the lagged data columns is used to 'preidct' the next day's value of the RIC via linear OLS regression

regs = {}
for ric in rics:
    df = dfs[ric] #getting data for the RIC
    reg = py.linalg.lstsq(df[cols], df[ric], rcond=-1)[0]
    regs[ric] = reg # storing the results
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [214], line 6
      4 for ric in rics:
      5     df = dfs[ric] #getting data for the RIC
----> 6     reg = py.linalg.lstsq(df[cols], df[ric], rcond=-1)[0]
**
File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in lstsq(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:2300, in lstsq(a, b, rcond)
   2297 if n_rhs == 0:
   2298     # lapack can't handle n_rhs = 0 - so allocate the array one larger in that axis
   2299     b = zeros(b.shape[:-2] + (m, n_rhs + 1), dtype=b.dtype)
-> 2300 x, resids, rank, s = gufunc(a, b, rcond, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
   2301 if m == 0:
   2302     x[...] = 0

UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'lstsq_n' input 0 from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Data for df[cols]:

```
                lag_1   lag_2   lag_3   lag_4   lag_5
Date                    
2022-01-24  2.967   2.989   2.997   2.929   2.919
2022-01-25  2.982   2.967   2.989   2.997   2.929
2022-01-26  2.984   2.982   2.967   2.989   2.997
2022-01-27  2.975   2.984   2.982   2.967   2.989
2022-01-28  3.011   2.975   2.984   2.982   2.967
... ... ... ... ... ...
2022-11-22  3.891   3.842   3.83    3.843   3.868
2022-11-23  3.921   3.891   3.842   3.83    3.843
2022-11-25  3.909   3.921   3.891   3.842   3.83
2022-11-29  3.833   3.909   3.921   3.891   3.842
2022-11-30  3.829   3.833   3.909   3.921   3.891
195 rows × 5 columns
```

Data for df[ric]

```
Date
2022-01-24    2.982
2022-01-25    2.984
2022-01-26    2.975
2022-01-27    3.011
2022-01-28    3.018
              ...  
2022-11-22    3.921
2022-11-23    3.909
2022-11-25    3.833
2022-11-29    3.829
2022-11-30    3.821
Name: MYMK180001=, Length: 195, dtype: Float64
```

i followed a tutorial eikon python api,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLt9keC0NtE

and i expect to achieve the results in minute 13:46

Comment: What does `np.asarray(df[col])` show?

Comment: Not sure if i answer your queries correctly, but 

py.asarray(df[cols])
array([[134.275, 134.21, 133.75, 133.59, 133.8525],
       [134.269, 134.275, 134.21, 133.75, 133.59],
       [134.5509, 134.269, 134.275, 134.21, 133.75],
       ...,
       [110.89, 110.5789, 110.5357, 110.4671, 110.565],
       [111.0468, 110.89, 110.5789, 110.5357, 110.4671],
       [111.0, 111.0468, 110.89, 110.5789, 110.5357]], dtype=object)

Comment: That clearly is an `object` dtype array, which is what `lstsq` is objecting to.  It appears to be (195,5) shaped.  `df.dtypes` may shed more light on why it's that dtype.  If the `.astype(float)` casting doesn't work, something must be going on.

Comment: Tks Paul, i have it worked by adding the .astype('float')

reg = py.linalg.lstsq(df[cols].astype('float'), df[ric].astype('float'), rcond=-1)[0]

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by adding `.astype('float')`:

```
reg = py.linalg.lstsq(df[cols].astype('float'), df[ric].astype('float'), rcond=-1)[0]
```